# Why is となって used here instead of になって

Tags: particle-と

～そんなテーマをもとに、コミュニティデザイナーの半沢直子さんがホスト役となって、各界で活躍する人たちと公開対談を行いました。

In this sentence they use と instead of に when they say 「ホスト役となって」

Does this change the translation from 'became a host'? And how does the meaning change - does it imply that this is the context under which she was working as for the following part of the sentence?